# Is a good practice using form tag's atributes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, coding-standards, html, standards, standardization

Checkout this HTML using the attribute `action`, `method` and `target` from `<form></form>` tag:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" target="_blank">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**Is a good practice using form tag's atributes in HTML?** It will redirect the user to another page. Isn't a better option always using XHR Requests?

JavaScript XHR example in JQuery with previous HTML code:

```
  $("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
      name: $("[name='fname']")
    },
    function(data,status){
    });
  });
```

Comment: I'm not a jQuery expert, so I can't speak to idioms there. But, in general, I think you'll find that form elements are *often* used to collect XHR parameters. Do you have a specific concern with doing this?

Comment: It's not good or bad practice, it's simply another way to submit data. Totally depends on your web framework and what you're comfortable with.

Comment: In software engineering there's very very few things that are _always better to use no matter the scenario_. XHR has become the facto standard to send request to servers but this is due to a trend or fashion. So basically to use one or another way is a matter of convenience and adecuacy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a technique that is used to allow websites to degrade gracefully if for some reason a browser doesn't have JavaScript turned on, or it is incompatible and the JavaScript engine crashes.

These days, between React, Angular, and several other frameworks that help build up the UI from formatted API calls (i.e. JSON, XML, etc.) and the world coming together around real web standards, the need to degrade gracefully is less important.

I will say that if there is no effective difference to the way the normal form `action` tag works, all you are doing is adding complexity for no gain.  If you are packing that into a JSON object to POST or PUT to an API, then the JavaScript is necessary.

The example you posted is much more concisely and clearly covered by the stock behavior of the HTML elements.  The JavaScript there isn't really performing any value, unless you are also going to perform validation and error handling without leaving the page.